# Maintain the first state of the view controller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have three UIViewController.When i go from Controller A to B then B to C then then to B again.The back button of a Navigationbar of controller B takes me to C.Is there a way to make sure that B's navigationbar back button takes me to A no matter how many times i go from B to C and C to B.Is this possible?

Comment: When the user goes from C to B, are you pushing a new B view controller, rather than popping back to the previous?

Comment: please add some code snippet from one you are using for navigation purpose.

Comment: if A is you root view controller you can use popToRootViewControllerAnimated by capturing the back button.

Comment: @johnpatrickmorgan i am pushing a new B view controller..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use custom back button with custom method in this case -

```
 UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backToViewController)];
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBtnItem;


   - (void)backToViewController
{
    int index =-1;
    for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

        index = index +1;

        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {

            if (index>0)
            {
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index-1]
                                                      animated:YES];
            }

            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the Controller A as root controller of your navigation & on click event of back button call `popToRootViewController` method instead of `popViewController`.

**Note :** **Here I have assumed that you have used custom bar button item.**